# TSQL - sql select records based on result set from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need help to derive the result as per below:

**TableA**

```
Metric
AA
BB
FF
```

**TableB**

```
Mth     AA  BB  CC  DD  EE
Jan     a1  b1  c1  d1  e1
Feb     a2  b2  c2  d2  e2
Mar     a3  b3  c3  d3  e3
```

**Expected Result**

```
Jan AA  a1
Jan BB  b1
Jan FF  NULL
Feb AA  a2
Feb BB  b2
Feb FF  NULL
Mar AA  a3
Mar BB  b3
Mar FF  NULL
```

Basically, I want to select the records from **TableA** based on Metric in **TableB** and display NULL if the column is not available.

I have come up with some ideas but still working on it, will post more details soon. Thanks.

Comment: `will post more details soon` ... no, please don't post a half-baked question here.  It looks like you want some sort of `UNPIVOT` result, but it is not entirely clear.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have just started with the solution in my head, I have posted the question anyway so that if someone like yourself has already dealt with it, can maybe help me.. but I do disagree that the question is half-baked, I have posted the source and expected result, so the question is actually complete.

Comment: Perhaps something like `SELECT B.Mth, A.Metric, U.col FROM tblA A CROSS JOIN (SELECT Mth FROM tblB) B LEFT JOIN (SELECT U.* FROM tblB UNPIVOT (col FOR Metric IN (AA, BB, CC, DD, EE)) U) U ON U.Metric = A.Metric AND U.Mth = B.Mth;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Tbl1.Mth,Tbl1.Metric,MthMetric
From 
(
  select distinct Mth ,Metric
  from TableB
  cross join TableA
)As Tbl1
Left Join
(
  SELECT u.MthMetric, u.ColVal,u.Mth --into ##TempDt
  FROM TableB s 
  unpivot( MthMetric
      FOR ColVal IN (AA,BB)) AS u
 )As Tbl2
 On Tbl1.Mth=Tbl2.Mth and Tbl1.Metric=Tbl2.ColVal
 Order by Tbl1.Mth,Tbl1.Metric
```

Comment: Select Tbl1.Mth,Tbl1.Metric,MthMetric
From 
(
  -- Returns Mth and it's available combination with TableA values
  select distinct Mth ,Metric
  from TableB
  cross join TableA
)As Tbl1
Left Join
(
  --Matches available Mth and Metric column--->mapping of Mth,Metric and respective value
  SELECT u.MthMetric, u.ColVal,u.Mth --into ##TempDt
  FROM TableB s 
  unpivot( MthMetric
      FOR ColVal IN (AA,BB)) AS u
 )As Tbl2
 On Tbl1.Mth=Tbl2.Mth and Tbl1.Metric=Tbl2.ColVal
 Order by Tbl1.Mth,Tbl1.Metric @JaydipJ